# How to reliably refill incendiary or other grenades?

Tags: the-division

When running challenging missions, or daily hard missions I tend to run out of grenades after 1-2 missions. I rely on stun or incendiary grenades for CC. I know only of the home base restock function that does not suffice.

**Are there other functions in the game to quickly refill grenades, besides random drops, such as stun or incendiary that are not found in restock boxes?**

Comment: If you're doing missions on hard, then you can fast travel to them, as they're already unlocked. It's hardly a chore to go back to BoO, restock and then fast travel to the next mission.

Comment: Restocking only fills standard grenades, not shock nor incendiary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your base of operations you can get them for free from the Rewards Claim Vendor. He's in the back behind the stairs to Tech Wing.

[image]

Comment: You need to claim a reward from the Uplay store before you can get these. I haven't actually grabbed them, as I was assuming you could only grab them once, and wanted to wait until I actually needed them. Can you just keep grabbing them?

Comment: Yep, they're just available the whole time.

Comment: incorrect. once you get the first ones from the 'ubisoft club go bag', they do not respawn.